# jsf f:selectItem setting empty string "" instead of null to value

Tags: jsf, primefaces

in my xhtml page, for `<selectOneMenu>` am setting null to itemValue in `<f:selectItem>` but am getting empty string "" but I want it as `null` below is my code please check and give me solution.

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="gender" required="false" value="#{pc_allotteeCreation.allotteeVO.aloteGender}" 
                 styleClass="col-xs-10 col-sm-5" 
                 requiredMessage="#{i18n['common.validation_message']}">

    <f:selectItem itemValue="#{null}" itemLabel="Select"  />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="Male" itemLabel="Male" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="Female" itemLabel="Female" />
    <f:selectItem itemValue="TransGender" itemLabel="TransGender" />

    <p:ajax update="gndmsg" event="blur" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
<p:message id="gndmsg" for="gender" showDetail="true"></p:message>
```

Comment: I don't even see any question mark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following lines to your web.xml to interpret empty Strings as null

```
    <context-param>
       <param-name>javax.faces.INTERPRET_EMPTY_STRING_SUBMITTED_VALUES_AS_NULL</param-name>
       <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
```

Comment: Worked a treat!

Answer (score 0):

The `h:selectOneMenu` returns a string type for the selected item. You need some server logic to map the returning string values to objects or `null`. Normally this can be done with a converter.

[Here is an example](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/custom-converter-in-jsf-2-0/) for a custom converter in JSF.